# Convrting String[ ] to BigInteger[ ] using split in java

Tags: java, biginteger

Basically what I want to achieve is that I have a string like this: `" 1 2 3 4"`. I want to store these elements in a BigInteger Array. I'm using below code, but to no avail:

```
String st1=br.readLine();
BigInteger arr[]=st1.split(" ");
```

But I get the following error:
`Cannot convert String[ ] to BigInteger[ ]`.
I know that I have an other way round: First store the elements to an intermediate array and then store all those elements to BigInteger array inside a loop. But I don't want to use this.

Is there any other way? Plesase help me with this.

Thank You!

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Readers might think that "I know how to do it but I don't want to do it that way" makes this question hard to answer without understanding your rejection criteria.

Comment: The rejection criteria is simple! I don't want to make another for loop!

Comment: So any other kind of loop would be acceptable? Even if the difference is arbitrary?

Comment: `" 1 2 3 4".split(" ")` returns `["", "1", "2", "3", "4"]`, so does that mean you want a `BigInteger[5]` array, where the first element is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BigInteger[] output = Arrays.stream(st1.split(" ")).map(BigInteger::new).toArray(BigInteger[]::new);
```

Do you want this method?

Comment: `NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger` since input `" 1 2 3 4"` has a leading space,

Comment: Amazing @bistros. Thank you, This solution is novel as well as efficient. I guess this is a tough one and I couldn't have guessed this solution.

Comment: @Andreas good. How about adding trim() too?  ex) Arrays.stream(st1.trim().split(" ")).map(BigInteger::new).toArray(BigInteger[]::new)

Comment: @Andreas that occured by mistake. bistros solution is right

Comment: @SatishTyagi Yes it is novel and convenient.  But there is a lot going on under the hood. The solution you wanted to avoid is more efficient (in terms of execution time).